# Dynamics CRM custom entity showing in accounts hierarchy

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, hierarchy

I have created a custom entity that, through the 'lookup' tool, I made to be the child of an accounts entity.

Now, I would like to show this custom entity in the accounts hierarchy. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can use only entities of one type in hierarchies. This is OOB behavior of CRM so you can show only child accounts under your account.

Comment: Thank you - what if instead of creating an entirely new entity, I used the 'product' tool. In doing so, would I be able to show that in the accounts hierarchy if I some how related the 'product' to my accounts entity?

Comment: As I already wrote in my initial reply (and nothing changed since that time) you can use only one type of entities in your hierarchies - http://www.powerobjects.com/2015/02/11/hierarchy-visualization-dynamics-crm-2015/ also check this - http://www.powerobjects.com/2015/03/30/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2015-custom-hierarchies/